# Waiting for the mount manager to create volume names

Tags: c, winapi, virtual-machine, vhd, mount-point

To mount vhds on windows, we can use `OpenVirtualDisk` then `AttachVirtualDisk` to attach a virtual disk, then `GetVirtualDiskPhysicalPath` can be used to obtain a physical path to the vhd, in the form of `\\.\PhysicalDrive1`.

Next we can use `FindFirstVolume` and friends to find the volume names the vhd contains. But this does not always work, as it can take some time for the mount manager to create a volume name symlink in the dos devices namespace to point to the physical volume.

How can we wait for this to happen, without doing busy-waits?